# Comma separated columns in CASE WHEN expression based on a condition

Tags: sql-server

I have my table as follows 0 is for UNKNOWN, 1 for NO and 2 says exposures exists. Lets say if I have multiple column values as 2 I would like to display as comma separated like ExposureA, ExposureB

```
CREATE TABLE ExposureDetails
([ExposureId] int, [ExposureA] INT, [ExposureB] INT, [ExposureC] INT);

INSERT INTO ExposureDetails
([ExposureId], [ExposureA], [ExposureB], [ExposureC])
VALUES
(1, 0, 0 ,2),
(2, 0, 0 ,0),
(3, 1, 1 ,1),
(4, 2, 0 ,2),
(5, 0, 1 ,0),
(6, 0, 1 ,1)
```

;

Here is the sample fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d043a/10 how to simplify with out writing many OR condition so that the output should be

```
Exposure(s)
ExposureC
UNKNOWN
NO
ExposureA, ExposureC
NO
NO
```

Comment: Can you please explain how you get 5 output rows from those 4 input rows?

Comment: Exposure(s) is column alias not output

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Comment: can be 2014 or later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this below script-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=38b37f2ffa432efd3542f17b5ab6e2a3)

```
select
case
    when [ExposureA] = 2 or [ExposureB] = 2 or [ExposureC] = 2 then
    (
        case when [ExposureA] = 2 then 'ExposureA' else '' end +
        case 
            when [ExposureB] = 2 and [ExposureA] = 2 then ',ExposureB'
            when [ExposureB] = 2 and [ExposureA] = 0 then 'ExposureB'
            else '' 
        end +
        case 
            when [ExposureC] = 2 and ([ExposureA] = 2 or [ExposureB] = 2) then ',ExposureC'
            when [ExposureC] = 2 and [ExposureA] = 0 or [ExposureB] = 0 then 'ExposureC'
            else '' 
        end
    )
    when [ExposureA]+[ExposureB]+[ExposureC] = 0 then 'NO'
    when [ExposureA] = 1 or [ExposureB] = 1 or [ExposureC] = 1 then 'UNKNOWN'
end as 'Exposure(s)'
from ExposureDetails
```

Comment: What about ExposureA = 0, ExposureB = 0, ExposureC = 1?

Comment: just considered case 0,1,2 from the sample data. And there is no scenario of having mixup of these three values in any row as per sample data. Either 0 everywhere or 1 everywhere or 2 in some columns.

Comment: `mkRabbani` yes there can be a case as seanb said

Comment: Even a case it can be 0,1,1

Comment: Your sample data should explain all possible combination and scenario.

Comment: If you can use a `CASE`, use the option presented here, but I suggest the logic should be: if there are any 2s, report them; else if there are any 0s, report it as unknown; else report it as NO.

Comment: Yeah sorry for that is my bad

Comment: Updated the question now

Comment: Updated my answer also the DEMO link

Comment: Hmm one more case like if I have `(7, 0, 1 ,2)` then it should display `ExposureC`

Comment: That is why I have written and conditions for 0 and 1

Comment: :) any more cases?

Comment: @Developer Please check my updated answer. The DEMO link also updated.